# Resource Graph query using Azure Function .NET and User managed Identity?

Tags: azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-resource-graph

In the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-dotnet) the DotNet-ResourceGraphClient requires ServiceClientCredentials. I do not know how to use a user-assigned-managed-identity directly.
For instance:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = umiClientId }); 
ResourceGraphClient argClient = new ResourceGraphClient(serviceClientCreds);
results in: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential' to 'Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials'.
```

I found a [PHP-example](https://cloud-right.com/2020/05/azure-functions-resource-graph) with credentials = MSIAuthentication(). Can anyone provide a similar example for dotnet-azure-resource-graph-sdk?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the input.
Authentication with user managed identity.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support

```
log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
// Connect client with user assigned managed identity.
string umiClientId = "<your-user-assigned-managed-identity-client-id>";
string conStrOpts = string.Format("RunAs=App;AppId={0}", umiClientId);
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(
                    conStrOpts
                );
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(
                        await azureServiceTokenProvider
                        .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/")
                        .ConfigureAwait(false)
                );
ResourceGraphClient argClient = new ResourceGraphClient(tokenCredentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

To acquire a token credential for your code to approve calls to Microsoft Graph, one workaround is to utilize the *ChainedTokenCredential*, *ManagedIdentityCredential* and *EnvironmentCredential* classes.

The following snippet generates the authenticated token credential and implements those to the creation of a service client object.

```
var credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
    new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
    new EnvironmentCredential());
var token = credential.GetToken(
    new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
        new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }));

var accessToken = token.Token;
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }));
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Access Microsoft Graph from a secured .NET app as the app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-easyauth-dotnet-storage-graphapi/tree/main/3-WebApp-graphapi-managed-identity#call-microsoft-graph-as-the-app)
2. [Tutorial: Access Microsoft Graph from a secured .NET app as the app](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app.md)